# In this Terraform config, why do I need to require variables in multiple places?

Tags: terraform

My folder hierarchy looks like this:

```
/
  -> live/
    : main.tf
    : variables.tf
  -> modules/
    -> logs/
      : logs.tf
      : variables.tf
```

In my `main.tf` I have:

```
module "logs" {
  source = "../modules/logs"

  env = var.env
  ...
}
```

In my `logs.tf` I have:

```
resource "datadog_monitor" "logs-fatal" {
  env = var.env
  ...
}
```

In both `variables.tf` files I have:

```
variable "env" {default = "test"}
```

If I remove this from either of them, I'm given an `Unsupported argument` error - why? It's unclear to me in this scenario which variable will be taking precedence and why both sets are needed.

Comment: Think of it like nested methods/functions in a programming language. If you had a function `a` with signature `foo, bar, baz` and then another function `b` that set `baz` to `false` but allowed the caller to set `foo` and `bar` then you still need to expose that in the signature for `b` as `foo, bar`.

Comment: Also this could be yet another argument for peer module design as opposed to nested. In other words, you may want to reorganize your module structure.

Comment: @MattSchuchard could you offer a link to 'peer module design'?

Answer (score 1):

In Terraform, each directory is treated as a separate namespace, and can be reused as a [module](https://www.terraform.io/docs/configuration/modules.html). As a rule of thumb you can assume that inside a directory you need to define all variables that are used in it.

Also, Terraform does not care about directory nesting, so even if `a` contains `b`, then `b` is entirely independent of `a`. If you want to include stuff from `b` from directory `a`, you need to pull in the whole thing as a module explicitly.